# Getting a error in the following code "! Missing delimiter (. inserted)."

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
\eta_{TEG}=\frac{P_{elec}}{\dot{\mathrm{m}} C_{p ex}\left(T_{in}-T_{out})\right}
\label{eq:tege}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you need a delimiter after `\right` either `\right)` or `\right.` if you want nothing

Comment: but you do not want `\left` or `\right` as there is no need to stretch the delimiters so just use `(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
\left(...)\right
```

but the correct syntax is

```
\left(...\right)
```

However, in your particular case such rescaling of brackets is completely unnecessary.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\eta_{\mathrm{TEG}}=\frac{P_{\mathrm{elec}}}{\dot{\mathrm{m}} C_{p\,\mathrm{ex}}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T_{\mathrm{out}}\right)}
=\frac{P_{\mathrm{elec}}}{\dot{\mathrm{m}} C_{p\,\mathrm{ex}}(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T_{\mathrm{out}})}
\label{eq:tege}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, I have made most of your subscripts `\mathrm`, but do not have enough context to know whether this is appropriate for the `C_{p ex}`.  If there really is a space in this subscript, then probably you want a thin space `\,` before the `C` too.